# How to implement a responsive layout with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive

I'm still beginner with JavaScript and ReactJS.

I'm doing a project to improve my knowledge. I have a layout with CSS and HTML already responsive. I'm trying to implement some logic wiht Javascript on my ReactJS project. When I click on my `burger-icon`, my `nav` open up, and when I click on my `close` icon, my `nav` close up. Can you tell me how can i do this?

As the layout is responsive only in HTML and CSS, for my `nav` to appear, it depends on the width of the screen.

[image]

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-gould-1ukfz?file=/src/views/home/Home.js:0-3359)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.scss";

const Home = () => {
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);

  const handleBurgerIcon = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setShowMenu(!showMenu);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex-container">
      <nav className="nav-categories">
        <div className="header">
          <h2>Categories</h2>
          <div className="close">
            <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 12 12">
              <g stroke="none" strokeWidth="1" fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
                <g
                  transform="translate(-318.000000, -363.000000)"
                  fill="#000000"
                  fillRule="nonzero"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M318.234315,373.616648 C317.921896,373.929067 317.921892,374.435597 318.23432,374.748025 C318.54673,375.060434 319.053273,375.060443 319.365691,374.748025 L329.548029,364.565687 C329.860447,364.253269 329.860438,363.746726 329.548029,363.434316 C329.235601,363.121888 328.729071,363.121892 328.416652,363.434311 L318.234315,373.616648 Z M319.365688,363.234318 C319.05327,362.921899 318.546746,362.921889 318.234318,363.234318 C317.921908,363.546727 317.921899,364.05327 318.234318,364.365688 L328.416655,374.548026 C328.729074,374.860445 329.235617,374.860435 329.548026,374.548026 C329.860454,374.235598 329.860445,373.729074 329.548026,373.416655 L319.365688,363.234318 Z"
                    fill="currentColor"
                  />
                </g>
              </g>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul className="nav-menu">
          <li className="active">
            <a href="#">Floral</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Fresh</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Gourmand</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Woody</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <section className="perfumes-list">
        <header>
          <div className="burguer-button" onClick={handleBurgerIcon}>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search by perfume" />
        </header>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div className="perfume-item">
              <div className="box-info">
                <div className="box-info--content">
                  <div className="description">
                    <h1>Kim Kardashian</h1>
                    <p>
                      In 2009, Kim Kardashian launched a perfume line with her
                      signature fragrance, called Kim Kardashian by Kim
                      Kardashian.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="tags">
                    <span>Woody</span> / <span>Oriental</span> /{" "}
                    <span>Gourmand</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="box-info--footer">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <span>Sample</span>{" "}
                      <h3>
                        Free<sup></sup>
                      </h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <span>Normal</span>{" "}
                      <h3>
                        38.00<sup>€</sup>
                      </h3>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

```css
:root {
  --white: #ffffff;
  --black: #111116;
  --gray: #f4f7f6;
  --gray-dark: #6c7680;
  --orange: #ff8f32;
}

body,
html {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: var(--black);
  text-align: left;
  background-color: var(--gray);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

p {
  color: var(--gray-dark);
}

.tags {
  color: var(--orange);
  text-align: right;
}

h1 {
  color: var(--orange);
  font-weight: 400;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.125rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

.flex-container > * {
  padding: 15px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.burguer-button {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burguer-button div {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
  background-color: var(--black);
  margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
}

input[type="search"],
input[type="text"] {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid var(--gray);
}

input:hover,
input:focus {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  cursor: auto;
  border: 1px solid var(--orange);
}

.nav-menu .active a {
  color: var(--orange);
}

.nav-menu a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #202121;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f4f7f6;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6eaea;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.nav-menu a:hover {
  background-color: var(--white);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.perfume-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 #e8ebed, 0 0 3px 0 #e8ebed;
}

.box-info {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  background-color: var(--white);
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.box-info--content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.box-info--footer {
  display: flex;
}

.box-info--footer ul {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.box-info--footer li {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
}

.box-info--footer li span {
  color: var(--gray-dark);
}

/*Nav Categories*/
.nav-categories {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 75%;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: var(--gray);
}

.nav-categories .header {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-categories .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.nav-categories ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-categories li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-categories li.selected {
  background-color: rgb(87, 87, 206);
  color: #ffffff;
}

.perfumes-list {
  flex: 1;
  order: 2;
  text-align: left;
}

.perfume {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.perfume ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

/*Pagination*/
.pagination {
  text-align: center;
  order: 3;
}

.pagination {
  width: 100%;
}

.pagination {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pagination li {
  margin-right: 0.25rem;
}

.pagination li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.pagination li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  color: var(--gray-dark);
  padding: 0.375rem 0.4375rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagination li a:hover {
  background: var(--orange);
  color: var(--white);
}

.pagination li a:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px var(--orange);
}

.pagination li a:active {
  background: var(--gray-dark);
  color: var(--white);
}

.pagination .active a {
  background: var(--orange);
  color: var(--white);
  pointer-events: none;
}

// 48em -> 768px
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .nav-categories {
    width: 40%;
  }
}

// 64em -> 1024px
@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .nav-categories {
    position: relative;
    top: unset;
    left: unset;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0;
    order: 1;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
  }

  .nav-categories .close {
    display: none;
  }

  .burguer-button {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Thank you advance!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cannot just use `class` attribute in react. In react it's `className`. [Click here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) for more info.

Handling events with React elements is very similar to handling events on DOM elements. There are just some syntax differences.

You can simply add an `onClick` listener to your burger-icon element and call a function that you create in your `Home.js`, like this.

```
<div className="burguer-button" onClick={handleBurgerIcon}>
```

Now we are going to create a boolean state and change the value everytime when button is clicked. This is how you create a state in a functional react.

```
const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = React.useState(false);
```

You can represent this like a variable with a getter and setter. And as default value we use `false`.

Now we create the function to handle the click.

```
const handleBurgerIcon = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  setShowMenu(!showMenu);
}
```

The function `setShowMenu` toggles the value of our `showMenu` state.

Finally we use a conditional rendering for our nav-menu. So it only gets visible, when our `showMenu` is true. This is how you can do it.

```
{showMenu &&
  <ul className="nav-menu">
    <li className="active">
      <a href="#">Floral</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Fresh</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Gourmand</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Woody</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
}
```

Comment: Hey Enucar, unfortunately it didn't work, I put the `css` here now to help

Comment: It doesn't show, because your `nav-menu` is hidden in CSS. You can simply add conditional class name like `show` to nav-menu when the menu is visible and force in CSS `nav-menu.show` to display and position it how you want. You can add conditional class name like this. https://i.imgur.com/WS1hPwh.png

Comment: It should be `!showMenu` not `showMenu` in the example image.

Comment: Hey Enucar, I will try to apply what you said, but I must apply the logic in `nav-categories`, right ?! Instead of `nav-menu`?